# Code works but I get No such element error after executing

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I'm using a for loop to repeat a task which basically deletes specific objects in my active Illustrator doc. The code works but when it ends I got an error and I'm unable to execute the rest of the code.

My code:

```
def top_file():
    for y in range(1, pathCount + 1):
        path_items = activeDoc.PathItems(y).Filled
        if path_items is False:
            path_items = activeDoc.PathItems(y)
            path_items.Delete()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joelq\Desktop\Joy Automation\main.py", line 88, in <module>
    top_file()
  File "C:\Users\joelq\Desktop\Joy Automation\main.py", line 61, in top_file
    path_items = activeDoc.PathItems(y).Filled
  File "C:\Users\joelq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 226, in __call__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs), self._olerepr_.defaultDispatchName, None
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, 'Adobe Illustrator', 'No such element', None, 0, -2147352565), None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty clear from the error message.  Collections in Illustrator's object model are numbered from 0, just like Python lists.  Use `range(pathCount)`.

Note, however, that what you're doing will fail later.  If you `Delete` an item from a collection while you are iterating the collection, the counts will be wrong.  If you delete item 3, then what was item 4 becomes item 3, and the number of items changes, so your `range` will be run off the end.  You may need to iterate backwards from the end instead.